# django ORM - Exclude on M2M with F-function not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='activities')
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='activities')


class Project(models.Model):
   assignees = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projects')
```

Now I want to query for all the activities which belog to a user which is NOT in the projects assignees.

My query:

```
Activity.objects.exclude(project__assignees=F('user'))
```

Problem is, I always get this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'U2.id' in 'on clause'")

Im working on django 2.2.11 and MySQL.

I found a couple of [old django bugs](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28551) but they are supposed to be fixed since ages.

Any ideas how I can solve my problem? My activity table is huge and I need an efficient way. And I'd be happy to not use raw queries.

Comment: When I inspect the query, it looks like it does not define an `U2` table at all. But you can fix this with a subquery I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug, since in the generated query, the `U2` table is not even defined. You might want to file a [ticket at Django's ticketing system](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Reports).

You can however solve the problem by annotating and then filtering:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Activity.objects.annotate(
    valid=~Exists(Project.objects.filter(
        activities=OuterRef('pk'),
        assignees=OuterRef('user')
    ))
).filter(valid=True)
```

or as of [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0), you can filter on the `Exists` directly:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Activity.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(Project.objects.filter(
        activities=OuterRef('pk'),
        assignees=OuterRef('user')
    ))
)
```

Comment: Created a ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31401#ticket